# Meteor Mongodb Bulk Update by _id not working

Tags: mongodb, meteor, bulkupdate

I'm trying to perform following bulk Update Operation by _id:

```
let bulk = Transactions.rawCollection().initializeOrderedBulkOp();

transactions.forEach((t) => {             
   let query = { '_id' : new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(t._id._str) };
   bulk.find( query ).update( { $set: { balance: t.balance, updated_at: new Date() } } );
});
bulk.execute(Meteor.bindEnvironment((err, res) => {
     if (!err) {
             callback(null, true);
      } else {
             console.log("Error Ocurred");
             callback(true, null);
       }
}));
```

But This find query by _id is not working. If I do query by any other field It works just fine. But I can't do that because Collection has only one Unique field as '_id'.

**EDITED**:

Following is Transaction MongoDB Document

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5899f8a15d79b02f6075100d"), 
    "transaction" : "Charge",
    "description" : "01/01/2017 - 01/28/2017", 
    "created_by" : "SYSTEM",
    "residency_id" : "6pFs3sBMZPtp3e5N9", 
    "value" : 25.82, 
    "balance" : 25.82, 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-02-07T16:41:05.718+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-02-07T18:08:05.378+0000")
}
```

Help Needed. TIA

Comment: Please include some of your `Transactions` documents, I doubt that it has something to do with the `_id` field value

Comment: @Khang I have updated the Question. Please check